# How to write apps that syncs to device's refresh rate?

Tags: android, animation, mobile, graphics

One one of the iPad's app website says - "to take full advantage of the iPad's graphics processing to create a fluid, 60 frames per second, experience." Wow! Moreover, Google Chrome's animation rate matches display refresh freq, say 60Hz.

My question: *With mobile platforms, how to write apps that syncs device's screen refresh rate and delivers smooth animation?*

Answer (score 0):

You should use animation APIs. See for instance the documentation of ValueAnimator:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ValueAnimator.html#setFrameDelay%28long%29

This documentation says: "The frame delay may be ignored when the animation system uses an external timing source, such as the display refresh rate (vsync), to govern animations." I don't know whether all devices use vsync (would be curious to test), but it sounds very much like the right way to get animation smoothness.

See the developer's guide about property animation:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html

In addition, there is an API that will give you the refresh rate:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html#getRefreshRate%28%29

```
((WindowManager)getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay().getRefreshRate();
```